# append prepend not working with jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

am trying to create simple slider with jquery. But I'm kinda stuck when cycling the item.

when I click next, first item should be replace into last and the opposite.
is there any suggestion to fix this cycle

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var slideItem = $('.slider-item');
 var slideContainer = $('.slide-container');
 var sliderWrap = ((slideItem.width() * slideItem.length)+ 100);

 $(slideContainer).css('width', sliderWrap+'px');

function next() {
 $(slideContainer).animate({'margin-left':'-=515px'},300,function(){
  $(slideItem).first().remove().appendTo(slideContainer);
  $(slideContainer).css('margin-left', '');
 });
}

function prev() {
 $(slideContainer).animate({'margin-left':'+=515px'},300,function(){
  $(slideItem).last().remove().prependTo(slideContainer);
  $(slideContainer).css('margin-left', '');
 });
}

$('.next').on('click', function(){
 next();
});

$('.prev').on('click', function(){
 prev();
});

});
```

```css
.thumbnail-gallery {
 margin-top: 160px;
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: green;
}

.slide-container {
 white-space: nowrap;
 background-color: red;
}

.slider-item {
 width: 500px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: yellow;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail-gallery">
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider-item">1</div>
    <div class="slider-item">2</div>
    <div class="slider-item">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.remove()` call is not necessary. Both `.appendTo()` and `.prependTo()` removes elements from `DOM` and appends or prepends element to selected parent element.

You can use jQuery object variable `slideContainer` as second parameter to `jQuery()` to set context to parent element, direct descendant selector `>`, jQuery `:eq()` with parameter `0` at `next` function and parameter `-1` at `prev` function to select the expected element from within `slideContainer` parent element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slideItem = $('.slider-item');
  var slideContainer = $('.slide-container');
  var sliderWrap = ((slideItem.width() * slideItem.length) + 100);

  $(slideContainer).css('width', sliderWrap + 'px');

  function next() {
    slideContainer.animate({
      'margin-left': '-=515px'
    }, 300, function() {
      $("> :eq(0)", slideContainer).appendTo(slideContainer);
      slideContainer.css('margin-left', '');
    });
  }

  function prev() {
    $(slideContainer).animate({
      'margin-left': '+=515px'
    }, 300, function() {
      $("> :eq(-1)", slideContainer)
      .prependTo(slideContainer);
      slideContainer.css('margin-left', '');
    });
  }

  $('.next').on('click', function() {
    next();
  });

  $('.prev').on('click', function() {
    prev();
  });

});
```

```css
.thumbnail-gallery {
  margin-top: 160px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.slide-container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
}

.slider-item {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail-gallery">
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider-item">1</div>
    <div class="slider-item">2</div>
    <div class="slider-item">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

Alternatively, you can use a single function for both `next`, `prev` function and `click` event handler by storing parameters passed to function as an array associated with the element, for example at `.data()` of `.next` and `.prev` elements

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slideItem = $('.slider-item');
  var slideContainer = $('.slide-container');
  var sliderWrap = ((slideItem.width() * slideItem.length) + 100);
  
  $(".next").data("args", ["-", "append", 0]);
  $(".prev").data("args", ["+", "prepend", -1]);

  $(slideContainer).css('width', sliderWrap + 'px');

  function nextPrev(sign, dir, index) {
    slideContainer.animate({
      'margin-left': sign + '=515px'
    }, 300, function() {
      $("> :eq("+index+")", slideContainer)[dir + "To"](slideContainer);
      slideContainer.css('margin-left', '');
    });
  }

  $(".next, .prev").on("click", function() {
    nextPrev.apply(this, $(this).data("args"));
  });

});
```

```css
.thumbnail-gallery {
  margin-top: 160px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

.slide-container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: red;
}

.slider-item {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thumbnail-gallery">
  <div class="slide-container">
    <div class="slider-item">1</div>
    <div class="slider-item">2</div>
    <div class="slider-item">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

Comment: I see I have to find the parent to move children, but some thing kinda weird when I can previous item, the animation doesn't work properly. Is it because force last-child into first-child?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: it is my expected result, still figure out on my prev animation to have same animation on next

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    setInterval(function () {
        moveRight();
    }, 3000);
  });
  
 var slideCount = $('#slider ul li').length;
 var slideWidth = $('#slider ul li').width();
 var slideHeight = $('#slider ul li').height();
 var sliderUlWidth = slideCount * slideWidth;
 
 $('#slider').css({ width: slideWidth, height: slideHeight });
 
 $('#slider ul').css({ width: sliderUlWidth, marginLeft: - slideWidth });
 
    $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');

    function moveLeft() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: + slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:last-child').prependTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    function moveRight() {
        $('#slider ul').animate({
            left: - slideWidth
        }, 200, function () {
            $('#slider ul li:first-child').appendTo('#slider ul');
            $('#slider ul').css('left', '');
        });
    };

    $('a.control_prev').click(function () {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $('a.control_next').click(function () {
        moveRight();
    });

});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600); 

html {
  border-top: 5px solid #fff;
  color: #2a2a2a;
}

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

#slider ul {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}

#slider ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 300px;
}

a.control_prev, a.control_next {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  z-index: 999;
  display: block;
  padding: 4% 3%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  background: #2a2a2a;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a.control_prev:hover, a.control_next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

a.control_prev {
  border-radius: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

a.control_next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
}

.slider_option {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 160px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
  <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
  <ul>
    <li>SLIDE 1</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 2</li>
    <li>SLIDE 3</li>
    <li style="background: #aaa;">SLIDE 4</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<div class="slider_option">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>
</div>
```